# Can't Make Two Identical QR Code Srtings Equal Each Other

Tags: string, powershell, qr-code

This is my first post on here.  I am pretty new to coding and Powershell so I might be missing something obvious here.  I made a QR code label maker for my work using Powershell and Smartsheet. Without getting into too much detail on that it pulls data from a line in a "Product Tracker" we made in Smartsheet and creates a label with a QR code from that data.  In one of the columns on that line it mimics the data produced when you scan the QR code. It mimics it like this....

```
$SkuCell.Value = "BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
KIND:individual
N:$($ptCO.Desc);$($ptCO.Po)
FN:$($ptCO.Po) $($ptCO.Desc)
ORG:All New Glass
EMAIL;TYPE=INTERNET:$($ptCO.Assign)
END:VCARD"
```

... and the output looks like this.....

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
KIND:individual
N:Test stuff here;12354
FN:12354 Test stuff here
ORG:All New Glass
EMAIL;TYPE=INTERNET:ericg@allnewglass.com
END:VCARD
```

Then on a different Smartsheet our drivers will scan the QR code on the label signifying that its leaving our hub.  The scanned data in that cell looks like this.....

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
KIND:individual
N:Test stuff here;12354
FN:12354 Test stuff here
ORG:All New Glass
EMAIL;TYPE=INTERNET:ericg@allnewglass.com
END:VCARD
```

I then have a different script checking for matches between the two sheets so In the product tracker we know when something leaves the hub.  The problem is that even though the scanned data and the mimicked data look absolutely identical and they both say they are strings, they never match.  They are not equal to each other and I have tried EVERYTHING ([string], out-string, convert-string, compare-object, trim, etc) I can think of to get them to match and the only thing that works is if I pipeline Out-Host on the objects.  However, these objects are contained in a foreach loop that checks through all the rows in both sheets which means that the script runs way to slow having to display all that data.  It seems likely that there are some hidden characters in the scanned data causing them to not match.  Can anyone think of a solution to make these two strings identical?  Is there a way of removing all hidden characters?  Or does anyone have a better idea?  A different way to compare them maybe?

Here's the code that tries to compare....

```
    # by GrEcHkO

#cd "C:\Users\Jacly\Desktop\ANG_System_Files"
cd "P:\ANG_System_Files"

function Load-Dll
{
    param(
        [string]$assembly
    )
    Write-Host "Loading $assembly"

    $driver = $assembly
    $fileStream = ([System.IO.FileInfo] (Get-Item $driver)).OpenRead();
    $assemblyBytes = new-object byte[] $fileStream.Length
    $fileStream.Read($assemblyBytes, 0, $fileStream.Length) | Out-Null;
    $fileStream.Close();
    $assemblyLoaded = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load($assemblyBytes);
}

function Get-ComparisonObjects
{
    param([Smartsheet.Api.Models.Sheet]$sheet)

    Write-Host "Getting Sheet $($sheet.Name) Comparison Objects"

    $data = $sheet.Rows | foreach {
        $checkVal = $false
        $trackedCheckVal = $false
        $finishedCheckVal = $false

        if($_.Cells[3].Value -eq $true)
        {
            $checkVal = $true
        }

        if($_.Cells[16].Value -eq $true)
        {
            $trackedCheckVal = $true
        } 

        if($_.Cells[12].Value -eq $true)
        {
            $finishedCheckVal = $true
        }
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Attachments = $_.Attachments;
            RowId = $_.Id;
            RowNumber = $_.RowNumber;
            Parent = $_.ParentId;
            PoCol = $_.Cells[0].ColumnId;
            Po = $_.Cells[0].Value;
            JobsCol = $_.Cells[1].ColumnId;
            Jobs = $_.Cells[1].Value;
            DescCol = $_.Cells[2].ColumnId;
            Desc = $_.Cells[2].Value;
            CheckCol = $_.Cells[3].ColumnId;
            Check = $checkVal;
            SupplierCol = $_.Cells[4].ColumnId;
            Supplier = $_.Cells[4].Value;
            AssignCol = $_.Cells[5].ColumnId;
            Assign = $_.Cells[5].Value;

            DestinationCol = $_.Cells[11].ColumnId;
            Destination = $_.Cells[11].Value;
            FinishedCol = $_.Cells[12].ColumnId;
            Finished = $finishedCheckVal;
            DueCol = $_.Cells[14].ColumnId;
            Due = $_.Cells[14].Value;
            DeliveryCol = $_.Cells[15].ColumnId;
            Delivery = $_.Cells[15].Value;
            TrackedCol = $_.Cells[16].ColumnId;
            Tracked = $trackedCheckVal;
            SKUCol = $_.Cells[18].ColumnId;
            SKU = $_.Cells[18].Value;

        }                                                  
    }| where {![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.Po)}  

    Write-Host "$($data.Count) Returned"      
    return $data                                           
}   

function Get-DriverComparisonObjects
{
    param([Smartsheet.Api.Models.Sheet]$sheet)

    Write-Host "Getting Sheet $($sheet.Name) Comparison Objects"

    $data = $sheet.Rows | foreach {
        $checkVal = $false
        $trackedCheckVal = $false
        $finishedCheckVal = $false
        $archiveCheckVal = $false

        if($_.Cells[2].Value -eq $true)
        {
            $checkVal = $true
        }

        if($_.Cells[8].Value -eq $true)
        {
            $trackedCheckVal = $true
        } 

        if($_.Cells[3].Value -eq $true)
        {
            $finishedCheckVal = $true
        }

        if($_.Cells[11].Value -eq $true)
        {
            $archiveCheckVal = $true
        }
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Attachments = $_.Attachments;
            RowId = $_.Id;
            RowNumber = $_.RowNumber;
            Parent = $_.ParentId;
            DayCol = $_.Cells[0].ColumnId;
            Day = $_.Cells[0].Value;
            DueCol = $_.Cells[1].ColumnId;
            Due = $_.Cells[1].Value;
            CompletedCol = $_.Cells[2].ColumnId; #########hidden
            Completed = $checkVal;
            CheckCol = $_.Cells[3].ColumnId;
            Check = $finishedCheckVal;
            SupplierCol = $_.Cells[4].ColumnId;#########hidden
            Supplier = $_.Cells[4].Value;
            AssignCol = $_.Cells[5].ColumnId;#########hidden
            Assign = $_.Cells[5].Value;
            JobNameCol = $_.Cells[6].ColumnId;
            JobName = $_.Cells[6].Value;
            MainCol = $_.Cells[7].ColumnId;
            Main = $_.Cells[7].Value;
            TrackedCol = $_.Cells[8].ColumnId;
            Tracked = $trackedCheckVal;
            PoNumCol = $_.Cells[9].ColumnId;
            PoNum = $_.Cells[9].Value;
            ModifiedCol = $_.Cells[10].ColumnId;
            Modified = $_.Cells[10].Value;
            ArchiveCol = $_.Cells[11].ColumnId;
            Archive = $archiveCheckVal;

        }                                                  
    } | where {![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.PoNum)}   

    Write-Host "$($data.Count) Returned"      
    return $data                                            
}   

function Get-AttachmentFromSmartsheet
{
    param (
        [long]$attachmentId,
        [long]$sheetId
    )

    Write-Host "Getting Attachement $attachmentId of Sheet $sheetId"


    try
    {
        $attachment = $client.SheetResources.AttachmentResources.GetAttachment($sheetId,$attachmentId)
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
        Write-Host ""
    }

    $downloads = New-Item -ItemType Directory ".\downloads" -Force 

    $filepath = "$($downloads.Fullname)\$($attachment.Name)"

    Write-Host "Downloading $filepath"

    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $attachment.Url -OutFile $filepath 

    Get-Item $filepath
}

function Save-AttachmentToSheetRow
{
    param(
        [long]$sheetId,
        [long]$rowId,
        [System.IO.FileInfo]$file,
        [string]$mimeType
    )

    Write-Host "Saving $($file.Fullname) to Sheet $sheetId"

    $result = $client.SheetResources.RowResources.AttachmentResources.AttachFile($sheetId, $rowId, $file.FullName, $mimeType)

    return $result
}

function Merge-DriverChecklistWithProductTracker
{
     param(
        [pscustomobject[]]$orbitalRecords,
        [long]$orbitalId
    )

    foreach ($orbitalRecord in $orbitalRecords)
    {
        $descFound = $false
        $skuFound = $false

        if ($orbitalRecord.Archive -eq $false)                                                                                           #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
        {                                                                                                                                #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
            foreach ($ptCO in $ptCOs)                                                                                                    #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
            {                                                                                                                            #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
                $orbitalQR = "$($orbitalRecord.PoNum)"                                                                                   #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
                $ptQR = "$($ptCO.SKU)"                                                                                                   #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
                $noParent = $false                                                                                                       #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
                                                                                                                                         #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
                if ($orbitalQR -eq $ptQR)                                                                                                #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
                {                                                                                                                        #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
                    $descFound = $true                                                                                                   #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
                    break                                                                                                                #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
                }                                                                                                                        #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
                                                                                                                                         #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
                if ($orbitalQR -eq $ptQR)                                                                                                #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
                {                                                                                                                        #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
                    $skuFound = $true                                                                                                    #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
                    break                                                                                                                #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
                }                                                                                                                        #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
            }                                                                                                                            #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
                                                                                                                                         #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
            if ($skuFound)                                                                                                               #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
            {                                                                                                                            #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
                if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($orbitalRecord.PoNum) -and ![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($ptCO.SKU))                   #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
                {                                                                                                                        #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
                    Write-Host "SKU found.  Updating data on PT."                                                                        #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
                                                                                                                                         #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
                    $destinationCell = [Smartsheet.Api.Models.Cell]::new()                                                               #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
                    $destinationCell.ColumnId  = $ptDestinationCol.Id                                                                    #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
                    $destinationCell.Value     = "ITEM SCANNED TO ANG TRUCK"                                                             #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
                                                                                                                                         #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
                    $shippedCell = [Smartsheet.Api.Models.Cell]::new()                                                                   #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
                    $shippedCell.ColumnId  = $ptShippedCol.Id                                                                            #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
                    $shippedCell.Value     = if ($orbitalRecord.Modified -ne $null){$orbitalRecord.Modified} else {[string]::Empty}      #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
                                                                                                                                         #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
                    $row = [Smartsheet.Api.Models.Row]::new()                                                                            #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
                    $row.Id = $ptCO.RowId                                                                                                #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
                    $row.Cells = [Smartsheet.Api.Models.Cell[]]@($destinationCell, $shippedCell)                                         #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
                                                                                                                                         #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
                    $updateRow = $client.SheetResources.RowResources.UpdateRows($ptId, [Smartsheet.Api.Models.Row[]]@($row))             #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
                }                                                                                                                        #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
            }                                                                                                                            #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP

            elseif ($orbitalRecord.PoNum -eq $ptCO.Po)
            {
                if ($descFound)
                {
                     if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($ptCO.Parent))
                     {
                         $noParent = $true

                     }

                    if ($noParent)
                    {
                        Write-Host "Updating Product Tracker with Driver Checklist $($orbitalRecord.PoNum) $($orbitalRecord.Main)"

                        $jobsCell = [Smartsheet.Api.Models.Cell]::new()
                        $jobsCell.ColumnId   = $ptJobsCol.Id
                        $JobsCell.Value      =  if ($orbitalRecord.JobName -ne $null){$orbitalRecord.JobName} else {[string]::Empty}

                        $descCell = [Smartsheet.Api.Models.Cell]::new()
                        $descCell.ColumnId   = $ptDescCol.Id
                        $descCell.Value      =  if ($orbitalRecord.Main -ne $null){$orbitalRecord.Main} else {[string]::Empty}

                        $checkCell = [Smartsheet.Api.Models.Cell]::new()
                        $checkCell.ColumnId  = $ptCheckCol.Id
                        $checkCell.Value     = $orbitalRecord.Completed

                        $assignCell = [Smartsheet.Api.Models.Cell]::new()
                        $assignCell.COlumnId    = $ptAssignCol.Id
                        $assignCell.Value       = if ($orbitalRecord.Assign -ne $null){$orbitalRecord.Assign} else {"ianz@allnewglass.com"}

                        $supCell = [Smartsheet.Api.Models.Cell]::new()
                        $supCell.COlumnId    = $ptSupplierCol.Id
                        $supCell.Value       = if (($orbitalRecord.Completed -eq $false) -and ($orbitalRecord.Supplier -eq "In Shop FAB")){$suppliers["$fabId"]} else {$suppliers["$DriveId"]}

                        $finishedCell = [Smartsheet.Api.Models.Cell]::new()
                        $finishedCell.ColumnId  = $ptFinishedCol.Id
                        $finishedCell.Value     = $orbitalRecord.Check

                        $row = [Smartsheet.Api.Models.Row]::new()
                        $row.Id = $ptCO.RowId
                        $row.Cells = [Smartsheet.Api.Models.Cell[]]@($JobsCell, $checkCell, $supCell, $assignCell, $finishedCell)
                        try
                        {
                            $updateRow = $client.SheetResources.RowResources.UpdateRows($ptId, [Smartsheet.Api.Models.Row[]]@($row))

                            $reference  = if ($orbitalRecord.Attachments.Name -ne $null){$orbitalRecord.Attachments.Name} else {[string]::Empty}
                            $difference = if ($ptCO.Attachments.Name -ne $null){$ptCO.Attachments.Name} else {[string]::Empty}

                            $compareResults = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $reference -DifferenceObject $difference -IncludeEqual -SyncWindow ([int]::MaxValue)

                            $missing = $compareResults | where SideIndicator -eq '<='
                            $missingAttachments = $missing.InputObject
                            $attachmentsToGet = $orbitalRecord.Attachments | where Name -in $missingAttachments

                            foreach($attachment in $attachmentsToGet)
                            {
                                Write-Host "Adding missing attachment $($attachment.name)"
                                $file = Get-AttachmentFromSmartsheet -attachmentId $attachment.Id -sheetId $orbitalId
                                $result = Save-AttachmentToSheetRow -sheetId $ptId -rowId $newRow.Id -file $file.FullName -mimeType $attachment.MimeType
                            }
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
                            Write-Host ""
                        }

                        if ($orbitalRecord.Check -eq $true)
                        {
                            $dateCell = [Smartsheet.Api.Models.Cell]::new()
                            $dateCell.ColumnId  = $ptShippedCol.Id
                            $dateCell.Value     = $orbitalRecord.Modified

                            $row = [Smartsheet.Api.Models.Row]::new()
                            $row.Id = $ptCO.RowId
                            $row.Cells = [Smartsheet.Api.Models.Cell[]]@($dateCell)
                            try
                            {
                                $updateRow = $client.SheetResources.RowResources.UpdateRows($ptId, [Smartsheet.Api.Models.Row[]]@($row))
                            }
                            catch
                            {
                                Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
                                Write-Host ""
                            }
                        }

                        if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($orbitalRecord.Due))
                        {
                            $dateCell = [Smartsheet.Api.Models.Cell]::new()
                            $dateCell.ColumnId  = $ptAnticipatedCol.Id
                            $dateCell.Value     = $orbitalRecord.Due

                            $row = [Smartsheet.Api.Models.Row]::new()
                            $row.Id = $ptCO.RowId
                            $row.Cells = [Smartsheet.Api.Models.Cell[]]@($dateCell)
                            try
                            {
                                $updateRow = $client.SheetResources.RowResources.UpdateRows($ptId, [Smartsheet.Api.Models.Row[]]@($row))
                            }
                            catch
                            {
                                Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
                                Write-Host ""
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            else
            {
                if (!($descFound -or $skuFound))
                {
                    if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($orbitalRecord.PoNum))
                    {
                        if ($orbitalRecord.Tracked -eq "$true")
                        {
                            Write-Host "Adding to Product Tracker from Driver Checklist $($orbitalRecord.Po) $($orbitalRecord.Main)"

                            $poCell = [Smartsheet.Api.Models.Cell]::new()
                            $poCell.ColumnId     = $ptPoCol.Id
                            $poCell.Value        = if ($orbitalRecord.PoNum -ne $null){$orbitalRecord.PoNum} else {[string]::Empty}

                            $jobsCell = [Smartsheet.Api.Models.Cell]::new()
                            $jobsCell.ColumnId   = $ptJobsCol.Id
                            $JobsCell.Value      =  if ($orbitalRecord.JobName -ne $null){$orbitalRecord.JobName} else {[string]::Empty}

                            $descCell = [Smartsheet.Api.Models.Cell]::new()
                            $descCell.ColumnId   = $ptDescCol.Id
                            $descCell.Value      =  if ($orbitalRecord.Main -ne $null){$orbitalRecord.Main} else {[string]::Empty}

                            $checkCell = [Smartsheet.Api.Models.Cell]::new()
                            $checkCell.ColumnId  = $ptCheckCol.Id
                            $checkCell.Value     = $orbitalRecord.Completed

                            $supCell = [Smartsheet.Api.Models.Cell]::new()
                            $supCell.COlumnId    = $ptSupplierCol.Id
                            $supCell.Value       = if (($orbitalRecord.Completed -eq $false) -and ($orbitalRecord.Supplier -eq "In Shop FAB")){$suppliers["$fabId"]} else {$suppliers["$DriveId"]}

                            $assignCell = [Smartsheet.Api.Models.Cell]::new()
                            $assignCell.COlumnId    = $ptAssignCol.Id
                            $assignCell.Value       = if ($orbitalRecord.Assign -ne $null){$orbitalRecord.Assign} else {"ianz@allnewglass.com"}

                            $finishedCell = [Smartsheet.Api.Models.Cell]::new()
                            $finishedCell.ColumnId  = $ptFinishedCol.Id
                            $finishedCell.Value     = $orbitalRecord.Check

                            $row = [Smartsheet.Api.Models.Row]::new()
                            $row.ToBottom = $true
                            $row.Cells = [Smartsheet.Api.Models.Cell[]]@($poCell,$jobsCell,$descCell,$checkCell,$supCell, $assignCell, $finishedCell) 

                            try
                            {
                                $newRow = $client.SheetResources.RowResources.AddRows($ptId, [Smartsheet.Api.Models.Row[]]@($row))

                                foreach($attachment in $orbitalRecord.Attachments)
                                {
                                    $file = Get-AttachmentFromSmartsheet -attachmentId $attachment.Id -sheetId $orbitalId
                                    $result = Save-AttachmentToSheetRow -sheetId $ptId -rowId $newRow.Id -file $file.FullName -mimeType $attachment.MimeType
                                }
                            }
                            catch
                            {
                                Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
                                Write-Host ""
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

Write-Host "Loading Dlls"
Load-Dll ".\smartsheet-csharp-sdk.dll"                     
Load-Dll ".\RestSharp.dll"
Load-Dll ".\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
Load-Dll ".\NLog.dll"

while($true)
{
    Write-Host "Fab Log to Driver List to Product Tracker system starting up."

    $DriveId = "" 
    $fabId   = ""
    $ptId    = ""

    $suppliers = @{
        $fabId   = "In Shop FAB";
        $DriveId = "DRIVER CHECKLIST";
    }

    $token      = ""
    $smartsheet = [Smartsheet.Api.SmartSheetBuilder]::new()
    $builder    = $smartsheet.SetAccessToken($token)
    $client     = $builder.Build()
    $includes   =  @([Smartsheet.Api.Models.SheetLevelInclusion]::ATTACHMENTS)
    $includes   = [System.Collections.Generic.List[Smartsheet.Api.Models.SheetLevelInclusion]]$includes

    Write-Host "Loading Sheets"

    $Drive  = $client.SheetResources.GetSheet($DriveId, $includes, $null, $null, $null, $null, $null, $null);
    $fab    = $client.SheetResources.GetSheet($fabId, $includes, $null, $null, $null, $null, $null, $null);
    $pt     = $client.SheetResources.GetSheet($ptId, $includes, $null, $null, $null, $null, $null, $null);

    Write-Host "Comparing Objects"

    $DriveCOs  = Get-DriverComparisonObjects $Drive
    $fabCOs    = Get-ComparisonObjects $fab
    $ptCOs     = Get-ComparisonObjects $pt

    Write-Host "Identifying Driver Checklist Columns"

    #NO SPACE... BODY CHARACTER LIMIT FOR STACK OVERFLOW

   Merge-DriverChecklistWithProductTracker -orbitalRecords $DriveCOs -orbitalId $DriveId 

   Write-Host "Driver Checklist to Product Tracker finished."

   Start-Sleep -Seconds 10

}
```

Comment: Please copy/paste the PowerShell code you are trying to do the comparison into the question as text. Without that, we cannot know what you are doing.

Comment: Try to output both strings to file if possible and do a file compare.

Comment: Ok, I gave that approach a shot.  I think it works, but it is so very slow in this new configuration I've got.  One sheet has about 2500 lines and the other has about 800 lines.  So it'll take about 5 hours to run through because of the foreach loop inside the foreach loop.  Anyone have any ideas on how to make this go way faster?

Comment: I started a new topic for the new issue relating to outputting the data to a file and comparing.  Sorry if I'm dong this wrong, but the new topic is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52766719/can-anyone-help-make-this-script-run-faster

Comment: Here is what i would like to know. What type is the data returned from the QR scanner? You can find out by using `$QRVarable.GetType()`

Comment: I had already checked that and it says its a string.